# Tablas Pivot Php y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, tablas, sql

En mi base de datos MySQL tengo esta tabla :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer con PHP para que se muestre asi?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo hice esto, pero no funciona correctamente.

```
<?php

require ("conexion.php");

$consulta01=" SELECT tipo ,
(CASE WHEN fecha='2020-01-01' THEN codigo ELSE '' END) AS '1',
(CASE WHEN fecha='2020-01-02' THEN codigo ELSE '' END) AS '2',
(CASE WHEN fecha='2020-01-03' THEN codigo ELSE '' END) AS '3'
FROM tabla
GROUP BY tipo";

$resultado01=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta01);

?>

<table class="tabla">

<tr><td>Tipo</td><td><p>01/01/2020</p></td><td><p>02/01/2020</p></td><td><p>03/01/2020</p></td></tr>

<?php
foreach ($resultado01 as $fila01) : 
?>

<tr>
<td><p><?php echo $fila01['tipo'] ;?></p></td>
<td><p><?php echo $fila01['1'];?></p></td>
<td><p><?php echo $fila01['2'];?></p></td>
<td><p><?php echo $fila01['3'];?></p></td>
</tr> 

<?php
endforeach;
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que sucede, es que repite en todas las columnas de código el primer codigo que ha encontrado.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario tratar de hacer el pívot con PHP, con MySQL podrías hacerlo y con PHP solo mostrarlo como una tabla normal.

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado por favor

Comment: Por favor el código como texto pues como imagen es ilegible